# Set "inherit top navigation from parent node" to yes in site template

Tags: navigation, onet

I am currently trying to set the button "use top navigation from parent node" from the default value no, to yes. After hours of google research, playing around with the site template (WSP) file, I still not able to come to a good solution.

I would like to automatically inherit the top navigation bar to a new created subsite. Creating a Site definition is not an option, because then I would have to start with my templates from scratch again.

I've read that I can modify this by changing the `Onet.xml` file, but which one shall I modify? the global `Onet.xml` , the site definition `Onet.xml` or the `Onet.xml` which is included in the site template wsp file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Click Manage Site features under site actions and activate  SharePoint Server Publishing. Now go to Navigation under Look and Feel then you will have the option of inheriting the top navigation from the parent site.

Comment: That is the OTB option. I would like to set the default value to automatically inheriting the top navigation bar from parent site to subsite. When creating a new site (based on a company template) the user must manually set the value (inherit top navigation bar from parent site) from no to yes. I would like to make yes the new default value.